# Django Rest Framework, Nested serializer on reads only, not nested on writes

Tags: django-rest-framework

Say I have a model `Foo`, that has a foreign key to model `Bar`. When reading the serializer data I would like to have the full child `Bar` object available for rendering the UI, e.g. (when the data is going to be placed in the template):

```py
class ReadFooSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    bar = BarSerializer()

    class Meta:
       fields = (..., 'bar', ...)
       ...
```

But when writing the serializer data (data posted via AJAX to the server), the posted data will just include an ID of Bar, the full object is not being edited. So in order to prevent these errors:

```
"Invalid data. Expected a dictionary, but got int."
```

I.e. it's about the full `Bar` object is expected but it only got an integer value for the ID,  I have to create another serializer:

```py
class WriteFooSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
       fields = (..., 'bar', ...)
       ...
```

In this simple example it's fine, but on complex serializers, I wish there was a way to specify only nest the serializer on reads, but not on writes, is it possible with DRF?

I have used inheritance in the past, to create a base serializer that both the read and write serializer inherit from, but it's messy trying to keep the `Meta.fields` definition dry.

The read and write serializers end up like these "beauties":

```py
class BaseFooSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    ...

class ReadFooSerializer(BaseFooSerializer):
    bar = BarSerializer

    class Meta(BaseFooSerializer.Meta):
        fields = BaseFooSerializer.Meta.fields + ['bar']


class WriteFooSerializer(BaseFooSerializer):
    bar_id = serializers.IntegerField()

    class Meta(BaseFooSerializer.Meta):
        fields = BaseFooSerializer.Meta.fields + ['bar_id']

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        return ReadFooSerializer(instance).data
```

Answer (score 2):

For exactly similar use cases I have always created a subclass of the serializer. As you are just receiving random json payloads to the view, serializers must be used to extract the defined information. What you send out and receive are just some serialized formats of the same data. Instead of customing single properties with the Meta.fields, just change the expected presentation to pk of any existing object.

I have tried various ways to achieve something without defining separate serializers, but I think simple derivatives of the serializer you are using on the detail-view and using `get_serializer_class` to flip and flop them for different actions or regarding query parameters etc. is the most hygienic way after all.

```
from core.models import Pizza, Topping
from rest_framework.serializers import ModelSerializer, PrimaryKeyRelatedField
from rest_framework.viewsets import ModelViewSet


class ToppingSerializer(ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Topping
        fields = '__all__'


class PizzaSerializer(ModelSerializer):

    topping = ToppingSerializer() # serialize all fields of the related model

    class Meta:
        model = Pizza
        fields = '__all__'

class CreatePizzaSerializer(PizzaSerializer):

    # when deserializing, this field must match the primary key of an existing
    # topping
    topping = PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Topping.objects.all())


class PizzaViewSet(ModelViewSet):

    queryset = Pizza.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PizzaSerializer

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        if self.action == "create":
            return CreatePizzaSerializer
        return PizzaSerializer
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am mot sure I understand your approach. If I had a `updatePizaaSerializer` that only requires some of the pizza fields, would you subclass `PizzaSerializer` and define a `Meta` for it that sets `fields` as required? I don't see how this approach is different to having a base class with the common fields and then extending it? (but I suspect it's my lack of understanding)

Comment: Effectually everything of course has the same end result. I have been working daily with drf for years, and I'm 100% confident that explicit is better than implicit. I would never use __all__ as the field set shown in as an example, because that always ties the serializer pretty much to whatever changes are done to the model itself. Listing the fields in a subclass serializer meta will always effectively decouple your stuff from models and other serializers, and you can see with one peek what a specific serializer is returning, even if you dont define serializer fields for each one of them.

Answer (score 1):

There are two main approaches:

1. First one mentioned @potato_cannon:

Create separated serializers for reading and writing data (random app with articles)

```
from rest_framework import serializers


class CategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = '__all__'

class ListArticleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  category = CategorySerializer()
    
  class Meta:
      model = Article
      fields = '__all__'

class CreateArticleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  
  class Meta:
      model = Article
      fields = '__all__'
```

Then we can choose right serializer in get_serializer method in viewset:

```
class ArticleViewSet(ModelViewSet):

    queryset = Article.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ListArticleSerializer

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        if self.action == "create":
            return CreateArticleSerializer
        return ListArticleSerializer
```

But i will recommend you to create mixin viewset that can choose right serializer in all viewsets automatically:

```
class ViewSetSerializerMixin:
    create_serializer_class: Optional[Serializer] = None
    update_serializer_class: Optional[Serializer] = None
    list_serializer_class: Optional[Serializer] = None

    def _get_serializer_class(
            self,
            *args,
            **kwargs,
    ) -> Optional[Type[Serializer]]:
        if self.Action == 'create':
            return self.create_serializer_class
        if self.action in {'update', 'partial_update'}:
            return self.update_serializer_class or self.create_serializer_class
        if self.action == 'list':
            return self.list_serializer_class
        return None

    def get_serializer_class(self) -> Type[Serializer]:
    serializer_class = self._get_serializer_class()
    if serializer_class:
        return serializer_class
    return super().get_serializer_class()
```

It will allow you to do something like this:

```
class ArticleViewSet(ModelViewSet):

    queryset = Article.objects.all()
    list_serializer_class = ListArticleSerializer
    create_serializer_class = CreateArticleSerializer
```

2. The second approach is to create your own class inherited from PrimaryKeyRelatedField, which will accept primary key, but on list show you detailed data.

You will need to to implement your own to_representation method, you can pass something like detail_fields kwarg, and then based on this information represent it. It will be pretty big mixix, because you have to handle not only int and str fields, but FK and M2M too.

Comment: I like your mixing approach, keeps it DRY